# I am using multiple queries to determine which of a set of filters generates an empty table. Is there a performant way to do this with a single query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Toy example of the problem I am facing.

Suppose I have a collection of filterClauses and a single underlying table. I want to figure out which of these filterClauses fully filter out the entire table and which ones do not.

I am currently performing many of these SQL queries (one for each filterClause).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table
WHERE {filterClause})
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Is there a better way to group all of these calls into a single query and get a result set back that is a mapping of filterClauses to whether it filtered out the entire table? I've considered approaches with CASE statements and UNION statements but am wondering if there are more efficient ways.

As an additional problem (optional), for each of the clauses that did not generate an empty table, I want to check certain things about the resulting table (i.e., whether a certain column  has strictly positive values or whether or not all rows left are non-null for all columns). With the single query per filter clause approach, I could do these checks on the individually filtered tables. Any suggestions for how I can perform these checks on a batch level too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As to checking the effect of the filters: Compare the table's total row count with the row count of matched criteria:

```
select
  count(*) as totalcount,
  count(case when {filterClause1} then 1 end) as filter1count,
  count(case when {filterClause2} then 1 end) as filter2count,
  ...
from table;
```

As to further narrowing that down in a batch: No idea right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your point but here is what I think you need:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table
WHERE {filterClause1})
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as filterLabel1,
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table
WHERE {filterClause2})
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as filterLabel2,...
```

This should give you a map of which conditions are true and which are false, if you want to verify more conditions in case one is true I only have one idea, and it only allows you to add one more verification:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table
WHERE {filterClause1})
THEN 
    (
      Select CASE WHEN
      {subFilterClause}
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
ELSE 0 END as filterLabel1
```

Obviously I do not recommend going this deep, it's better to have a procedure either on SQL side or Application side to get it done for you.